# Solve Non-Homogeneous Equations In Order 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the following:
$$ y'''-10y''+32y'-32y=(2x-3)e^{4x}$$
$$y(0)=1,y'(0)=5,y''(0)=22$$
what I did:

1. $y=y_{Homogeneous }+y_{Private} \rightarrow y_{h}+y_{p}$

LHS : $y'''-10y''+32y'-32y=0 \rightarrow K^3-10K^2+32K-32 \rightarrow (K-4)^2(K-2)$
we get: $y_{h}=C_{1}e^{4X}+C_{2}Xe^{4X}+C_{3}e^{2X}$

RHS: $f(x)=(2x-3)e^{4X}\rightarrow y_{p}=AX^2e^{4X}+BX^3e^{4X}$

this is the level that I dont know how to continue, I need to differentiate $y_{p}\rightarrow y'p,y''p,y'''p$ then to  compare coefficients?
thanks.

Comment: There is a minor typo in your post : it is (K-4)^2 (K-2) and not (K-4)^2 + (K-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular solution should not have arbitrary constants. That is you when find the particular solution ($y_p$) you should have found the values of $A$ and $B$. The correct answer is,

$$y_p(x)=\frac{1}{6}x^3 e^{4x}-x^2 e^{4x}$$

Comment: I know, I Had trouble finding the coefficients, how did you find them?

Comment: One of the easiest methods, since you know that, $y_{p}=AX^2e^{4X}+BX^3e^{4X}$ is plugging $y_p$ into the left hand side of the differential equation and find out the values of $A$ and $B$ by comparing coefficients.

Comment: ok, what I`m doing with the third derivative?, I think there is a reason they gave me $y'()=\dots$

Comment: You'll have to differentiate $y_p$ thrice. The reason they have given you those initial values is that you can find the constants $c_1,\,c_2$ and $c_3$.

Comment: I did it, have a look, its huge:  $$y'p=4Ae^{4x}x^2+2xAe^{4x}+4Be^{4x}x^3+12x^2Be^{4x}$$ $$y''p=16Ae^{4x}x^2+16xAe^{4x}+2Ae^{4x}+16Be^{4x}x^3+12x^2Be^{4x}+23xBe^{4x}+48x^2Be^{4x}$$ $$y'''p=64Ae^{4x}x^2+64Axe^{4x}+16Ae^{4x}+64Be^{4x}x^3+48Be^{4x}x^2+216Be^{4x}x+204Be^{4x}x^2+24Be^{4x}$$

Comment: Yes, the algebra is tedious, but I am sure you are going the right path provided your calculations are correct. So plug in those values to the equation and try to compare the coefficients. :)

Comment: You can also check your answer in the below link. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27-10y%27%27%2B32y%27-32y%3D%282x-3%29e%5E%284x%29 Use the step-by-step feature.